# How can i break a line text using PHP for an email

Tags: php, actionscript-3, email, line-breaks

Using a AS3 aplication, i'm sending the body variable via GET.

```
$body = $_GET['body'];
```

Here i'm trying to replace the word 'JUMP' with '\n' to break a line

```
$body = preg_replace('/JUMP/', '\n', $body);
```

And here i'm trying to send an email with the lines break.

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)
```

But it's not working,

**Original message:**

Hi! JUMP I'm testing.

**E-mail:**

Hi! \n I'm testing.

**What I need:**

Hi!

I'm testing.

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$body = preg_replace('/JUMP/', PHP_EOL, $body);
```

Predefined Constant: [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

Answer (score 4):

\n only works when using double quotes around it otherwise it will be printed as defined.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$body = preg_replace('/JUMP/', '\n', $body);
```

to

```
$body = preg_replace('/JUMP/', "\n", $body);
```